# Convert Image to base64 and vice versa in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, flask

i wanted to convert this image to Base64 in unity C#
But I am kind of lost, can someone help?
This is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.Networking;


public class GetCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webCam;
    string your_path = "C:\\Users\\Jay\\Desktop";
    public RawImage display;
    public AspectRatioFitter fit;

    public void Start()
    {
        webCam = new WebCamTexture();
        webCam.Play();

        if(WebCamTexture.devices.Length==0)
        {
            Debug.LogError("can not found any camera!");
            return;
        }
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < WebCamTexture.devices.Length; i++)
        {
            if (WebCamTexture.devices[i].name.ToLower().Contains("your webcam name"))
            {
                Debug.LogError("WebCam Name:" + WebCamTexture.devices[i].name + "   Webcam Index:" + i);
                index = i;
            }
        }
    }

   
    public void Update()
    {
        float ratio = (float)webCam.width / (float)webCam.height;
        fit.aspectRatio = ratio;


        float ScaleY = webCam.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
        display.rectTransform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, ScaleY, 1f);

        int orient = -webCam.videoRotationAngle;
        display.rectTransform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, orient);
    }


    public void callTakePhoto()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakePhoto());
    }

    IEnumerator TakePhoto()  
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D photo = new Texture2D(webCam.width, webCam.height);
        photo.SetPixels(webCam.GetPixels());
        photo.Apply();

        //Encode to a PNG
        byte[] bytes = photo.EncodeToPNG();
       
        //Convert PNG to Base64


        //Write out the PNG. Of course you have to substitute your_path for something sensible
        File.WriteAllBytes(your_path + "\\photo.png", bytes);
        //lol
    }

    public void callpostRequest()
    {
        StartCoroutine(postRequest("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"));
    }

    IEnumerator postRequest(string url)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("name","hi from unity client");
        // form.AddField("nice","ok");

        UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Post(url, form);
        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
        StartCoroutine(getRequest("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"));

        if (uwr.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator getRequest(string uri)
    {
        UnityWebRequest uwr = UnityWebRequest.Get(uri);

        yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();

        if (uwr.isNetworkError)
        {
            Debug.Log("Error While Sending: " + uwr.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Received: " + uwr.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

For now all it does is click picture and save it to desktop and then below is the code of UnityWebRequest class which sends a hi message to a flask server and receives back the same

What i want to do is convert image to base64 and send to flask server, can anyone help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general you would simply do [`Convert.ToBase64String(byte[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string)

```
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

and accordingly [`Convert.FromBase64String(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.convert.tryfrombase64string)

```
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
```

---

Why though?

Images are "big" binary data. Base64 blows each byte up into hexadecimal chars which adds a lot of overhead.

=> Why not rather send the binary data directly?

See [`MultiPartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html) and use the overload [`public static Networking.UnityWebRequest Post(string uri, List<IMultipartFormSection> multipartFormSections);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html)

like e.g.

```
IEnumerator Upload(byte[] fileContent)
{
    var sections = new List<IMultiPartFormSection>();

    // According to your servers needs
    sections.Add(new MultiPartFormFileSection("files", fileContent, "photo.png", "image/png"));

    using(UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", sections))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");

            // Get the server response
            // NO NEED FOR A GET REQUESTS!
            var serverResponse = www.downloadHandler.text;

            Debug.Log(serverResponse);
        }
    }
}
```

and for the downloading accordingly use [`UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture.html) like

> ```
> using (var uwr = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture("https://www.my-server.com/myimage.png"))
> {
>     yield return uwr.SendWebRequest();
>
>     if (uwr.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
>     {
>         Debug.Log(uwr.error);
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         // Get downloaded texture
>         var texture = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(uwr);
>         ...
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: can i send image in bytes data without adding the part which actually saves it? since saving part was just for test purposes and this code will be deployed on phones soo yeahh

Comment: @Jay Well yes of course, simply directly pass on the `byte[]` as parameter then